# Brute force: count number of sub strings in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, brute-force

What I am supposed to do is create an algorithm that counts the number of substrings in a piece of text where the substrings can be the letter B followed by C or C followed by B. I'm not sure what to do, but I tried it and came up with the result below. I'd like to know if I did it correctly.

```
int substrCount(String S[0...n-1]){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<=n-2; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<i+2; j++) {
            if ((S[i] == 'B' && S[j] == 'C' ) || (S[i] == 'C' && S[j] == 'B')) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am gonna ignore whether it includes lowercase or uppercase for now. I also need to find the complexity of the algorithm from which I believe it is O(n^(2)). Did I do this correctly? If so, can I make it any more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

This works well for me

```
static int substrCount( String str) {
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++)
    {
        boolean bc = (str.charAt(i) == 'B' && str.charAt(i+1) == 'C');
        boolean cb = (str.charAt(i) == 'C' && str.charAt(i+1) == 'B');
        if (bc || cb) {
            count++;
        }
    } 
    return count;
}
```

You need to loop the sequence of chars in string just once to get the desired result. Check the couple of chars if they are equal "BC" or "CB" and move one index forward to the end of the string.

Output example:

```
"ACBAA" gives result 1
"ABCBA" gives result 2
"BCBCB" gives result 4
"BBBBB" gives result 0
```